# Variegated green/white plant

Tags: identification

After a thorough research of this plant, including this website, I cannot determine the name of this plant. It has green/white variegated leaves and no flowers present.

[image: 1]

Comment: Are there little hooks on the edges of the leaves?

Comment: The most beautiful plant in the world. I see a bromeliad, a succulent, or plastic. Too perfect.

Comment: To Kevinsko.  The leaves do curl under.

Comment: To Yosef Baskin. So by plastic, it may be fake?

Answer (score 4):

Closest I can find is *Agave desmettiana 'Quicksilver'* - the ones in your image look absolutely, even impossibly perfect compared with other images of this plant though, and the leaves are somewhat more curled over, so not 100% sure this ID is entirely accurate. The only links that offer photos of this plant are sales links, unfortunately - here's one of them https://mybageecha.com/products/agave-desmettiana-mediopicta-quicksilver

Comment: Another link claims this is Collector Agave - MP Variegated Agave Desmetiana.  Probably correct although misspelled

Comment: Yes, absolutely, even impossibly perfect.